# How can I make a dropdown tree with select2 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've been trying to create an dropdown tree with my json. It represents  two categories with a list of products.

Here my JSON Array:

```
    [
    {
    "reference":'BC-ENFANT',
    "name":'Pour les Enfants',
    "description":'Soins pour les enfants...',
    "id":155,
    "productList":[
    {"id":13655,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_01',"name":'Brushing'},
    {"id":13656,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_03',"name":'Soins'},
    ]
    },
    
    {
    "reference":'BC-FEMME',
    "name":'Pour les Femmes',
    "description":'Prestations pour les femmes',"id":154,
    "productList":[
    {"id":13657,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_01',"name":'Brushing'},
    {"id":13658,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_03',"name":'Soins'},
    ]}]
```

I have been only able to populate a simple select2 with those lines (Using Ajax call) :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="prestationCombo">Prestation</label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <select type="text" id="benefitList" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
        $.post("BookingManager/CategoryResult",
                                {
                                    shopId: shopId
                                },
                                function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    $('#benefitList').select2({
                                        multiple: false,
                                        data: data.map(c => { return c.reference }),
                                        dropdownParent: $('#emptyEvent'),
                                        placeholder: 'Rechercher une prestation...',
                                    });
                                }
    );
```

I have already used select2 but never find a way to get a proper solution to this problem.

Comment: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data 
The child data needs to be in the "children"key and the name in text

Comment: @PrikeshSavla I see, as the JSON is generate by my company, I cannot change de format of it. Maybe, I can creation another JSON with "children" and "text" properties and put the necessary into it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response format of your AJAX call is not in the correct structure for grouped data within Select2.

This can be fixed by using the `ajax` property of the Select2 library along with `processResult`. The latter will accept the AJAX response and can be used to convert the data in to the format Select2 needs in order to display [grouped options](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data). Try this:

```js
$('#benefitList').select2({
  multiple: false,
  ajax: {
    url: 'BookingManager/CategoryResult',
    type: 'POST',
    data: params => {
      term: params.term, // include the search term in the request
      shopId: shopId
    },
    processResults: data => {
     let results = data.map(group => ({
        text: group.name,
        children: group.productList.map(product => ({
          id: product.id,
          text: product.name
        }))
      }));
    
      return { results };
    }    
  }
  dropdownParent: $('#emptyEvent'),
  placeholder: 'Rechercher une prestation...',
});
```

For reference this is what the grouped data structure output will look like:

```js
let data = [{"reference":'BC-ENFANT',"name":'Pour les Enfants',"description":'Soins pour les enfants...',"id":155,"productList":[{"id":13655,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_01',"name":'Brushing'},{"id":13656,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_03',"name":'Soins'},]},{"reference":'BC-FEMME',"name":'Pour les Femmes',"description":'Prestations pour les femmes',"id":154,"productList":[{"id":13657,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_01',"name":'Brushing'},{"id":13658,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_03',"name":'Soins'}]}]

let results = data.map(group => ({
  text: group.name,
  children: group.productList.map(product => ({
    id: product.id,
    text: product.name
  }))
}));

console.log({ results });
```